# Nodejs async setup function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I am currently switching from Nodejs v12 to v14 and it seems that v14 does not wait for the setup function to resolve anymore. I use Nodejs combined with Express. My code looks like this (simplified):

```
setup().then(context => {
    // app setup based on context 

    app.listen(8080)
})
```

Is there a prefered way to use an async setup function before initializing the rest of the application?

The setup function connects the database and return a single promise like so:

```
function setup() {
    // This is a postgres library that return a promise
    return db.connect(this.config);
}
```

On Node v12 it seems to await the promise and start listening on the specified port after it is done. However when I switch to version 14 it does not await the promise and gives a clean exit.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that there isn't enough information in the question for us to be able to help you. What does "not finish anymore" mean? What is `setup`? What have you seen in your debugging? What is `db`? What does `db.connect` return?

Comment: I have elaborated

Comment: Try to add `.catch` to see if you have any failure `setup().then(context => app.listen(8080)).catch(err=>console.error(err));`

Comment: There are no errors, the only difference is the node version. Works fine on Node v12 but does not work on Node v14

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using async/await?

Try modifying function as shown below

```
async function setup() {
  
  await db.connect(this.config);
  
  app.listen(8080)

}
```

Comment: Also tried this structure, and this does not work.